# Xpages: Searching for documents I have no access to

Tags: security, xpages

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible but I'm going to ask anyway.

I am building a system which handles patient records. A new user needs to be able to search for a patient and once found request access to their files from the Admin.

How do I show a list of all documents even if the user has no access to them? They only appear in the view once they've been added to the Readers field, which defeats the purpose of the search.

My plan is to create 2 documents - the original patient document and a stripped-down document containing name, address used only for searching

Is there a better way of doing this, or is the 2 document approach the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sessionAsSigner to get database object on rights of database signer and run search on it. This will give You collection of documents that can be visualized similarly to view with use of data table.

Example (for moderate views works great - for bigger ones probably some optymalization would be necessary):

```
 <xp:panel id="viewPanel" styleClass="usersPanel">
    <xp:this.dataContexts>
        <xp:dataContext var="usersList">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:               
var uview = sessionAsSigner.getCurrentDatabase().getView("someView");
uview.FTSearch("Some query");
return uview.getAllEntries();
 }]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:dataContext>
    </xp:this.dataContexts>
    <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
        xp:key="headerPager" id="pager2" for="usersList">
    </xp:pager>
    <xp:dataTable id="usersList" rows="30"
        var="entry" value="#{usersList}">

        <xp:column id="column1">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:span xp:key="header"
                    styleClass="frameworkViewColumnHeader">
                    Użytkownik
                </xp:span>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                value="#{javascript:entry.getColumnValues().get(0)}">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:column>
        <xp:column id="column2">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:span xp:key="header"
                    styleClass="frameworkViewColumnHeader">
                    Instytucja
                </xp:span>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2"
                value="#{javascript:entry.getColumnValues().get(1)}">
            </xp:text>
        </xp:column>
    </xp:dataTable>
 </xp:panel>
```

Comment: after the search, would the user then have access to the documents or would this be governed by the ACL as normal?

Comment: The signer rights will be granted only for time of search and data table rendering. Access to documents when for example he will try to open them will be governed by the ACL

Comment: Great thanks. So the data source for the table would be - sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(session.getServerName(),session.getCurrentDatabase().getFilePath()).getView("VIEW NAME") ??